# Array to String conversion error in Codeigniter. result_array() and array_unique()

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I just what to turn the result array from my query (which is only has one column) to a unique array so it doesnt have repeated elements.

I don't know what else to do, I've tried everything, what am I doing wrong?

Model:

```
public function get_info()
    {
        $this->db->select('column');
        $this->db->from('table');
        $query=$this->db->get()->result_array();

        $out=array_unique($query);
        return $out;

    }
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('the_model');
    $data['stuff']=$this->the_model->get_info();
    $this->load->view('the_view',$data);
}
```

View:

```
       <?php 
          foreach($stuff as $i)
         {
          echo "$i['column']}";
         }
        ?>
```

The error I get is this:

```
A PHP Error was encountered 
Severity: Notice 
Message: Array to string conversion 
Filename: models/the_model.php
```

Comment: why are you trying to apply `array_unique` on the fetched result set, just add a `DISTINCT` in the query

Comment: Im really bad at this, im learning, thank you for the answer! although I still wonder why It doesn't work :/

Comment: `array_unique` doesn't work on that fetched array since this will result into multi dimensional row array, it must be a flat one, and by doing that thing is the wrong approach, just use a `distinct` which is also available in active record and you'd have unique values, then you just simply fetch.

Comment: edit with your print_r($query)

Comment: if the answer was given, please provide it in the answer area below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a DISTINCT in the query so the result doesn't have repeated values.

```
public function get_info()
{
    $this->db->select('column');
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->from('table');
    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array();

    $out=array_unique($query);
    return $out;

}
```